# combine 2 files in python without intersecting elements

Tags: python

I have 2 (file1.txt, file2.txt) files and want to combine them into a new file (target_file.txt) but without intersecting elements.
I need to retain the duplicates in this process, so can't use set().
Some explanation:
file1.txt has rows which contain duplicates ( rows coming from MQ) ----- want to write all these rows to target file.
file2.txt ------ will have some rows which are already present in file 1 ( this is coming from MQ after a restart of program, so MQ sysnchpoint would have restored these rows) + NEW rows which could be again have duplicates.
Ultimately, want to ignore those intersecting rows & write remaining.
eg: file1.txt has  54,834 rows.
file2.txt has  48,402 rows. (here 834 rows are same as in file1.txt)
Target file should have 102,402 rows. (48402 + 54834 = 103,236 – 834 = 102,402)

Comment: What order do you want the lines of the text file to be in?

Comment: So probably you only want to remove the lines from file2, if they are at the beginning of file2 and the duplicates at the end of file1, right? And actually you expect a block of lines to be identical -- at the end of file1 and the beginning of file2, right?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark --- There's really no order of data as data is coming through MQ & it can be any data type eg: JSON, XML etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
  f1 = file.readlines() # list

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file:
  f2 = file.readlines() # list

f = [*f1]
f.extend(f2)

dedup = set(f)

s1 = set(f1)
s2 = set(f2)

dup = set.intersection(s1, s2)

print("Unique lines:")

for line in dedup:
  print(line, end='')


print("\nDuplicated lines:")

for line in dup:
  print(line, end='')
```

#### Explanation

The files are first loaded into lists (line by line) `f1` and `f2`. They are then merged into list `f`.

Then we create set `dedup` of list `f` and because set can contain each element only once, we have our result. Also we create sets `s1` and `s2` from `f1` and `f2` and intersect them into set `dup` using which we get all duplicated lines.

Finally, we can print every element in sets - without newlines, because the elements already contain them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def readtxt(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as file:
        f = file.readlines()
    return f
f1=readtxt('file1.txt')
f1.extend(readtxt('file2.txt'))
f2=[]
[f2.append(f) for f in f1 if f not in f2 ]
```

the `f2` here is desired list, the difference between my code and the stanstny's code is that it's not all alphabetically sorted, and the orders are the same of appearance in the two text files.